# what is the difference between equality operator and the identical operator in php

Tags: php

equality operator (==) and identity operator (===), what is the difference between these two?
I read through the definition provided in our text book , but it doesn't explain the difference between the two very well.

I am not understanding what the difference between two are. i understand the equality operator (==).  But i am confused when/how the identity operator can be useful or considered a better choice.

we can only compare two things if their types are equal , correct?

- sorry if my question isn't very clear / worded correctly.... apologize in advance..

Comment: `0=='0'  //true` , `0==='0' //false` must be same type and value

Comment: The docs actually cover this quite well: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php